# Get list of all loaded classes through JMX

Tags: classloader, jmx

I have a little Java program that makes a JMX connection to a remote Weblogic server. I want to get a list of all loaded classes.

I have an `ObjectName` object with for `"java.lang:type=ClassLoading"`.

(How) is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The default JVM platform MXBeans don't publish this information.